# Websocket Server is being timeout after 90 seconds

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, wildfly

I am implementing a websocket and using jakarta.websocket.server.ServerEndPoint class to have a websocket server serving task for the client.

FYI - I am working to upgrade the javax.* to jakarta.* for wildfly compatibilty there when i am seeing client disconnection after 90 seconds.

I am seeing that all the client being terminated abnormally after specifically 90 seconds,
2023-09-18 17:24:39 INFO  INVENTORY_UPDATES:131 - Connection closed: CloseReason[1006,Closed abnormally.]

Any Pointer someone can provide to check on this as i am completely blocked to get the exact root cause for the same , Let me know if you need any more info.
Wildfy 29.0.0 version being used for server.

Comment: You're likely seeing what is described here https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-18082.

Answer (score 0):

Like James R. Perkins commented, this is caused by a change in Wildfly 28 that set a default of 90 seconds for read and write timeouts for the http(s)-listener, see https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-14980.

To change back to the old behavior, look for a 'http-listener' and/or a 'https-listener' element in the 'undertow' subsystem in the standalone.xml you are using. There you can set the timeouts with two new attributes:

```
read-timeout="0" write-timeout="0"
```

The value of 0 means unlimited.